# Как правильно написать временной интервал?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Скажите, пожалуйста, можно ли писать временной интервал с предлогами «с/до».
Например:
Он сможет посмотреть с 16:00-17:00.

Answer (score 1):

Можно, но с использованием **пары предлогов С, ДО**:

***Он сможет посмотреть с 16:00 до 17:00.***

Без предлогов могут быть варианты оформления:

16.00 - 17.00 - время просмотра.

Comment: Благодарю! Как раз так и думал, но нигде не находил ответа. Поэтому нужен был человек, который озвучил бы мои мысли :)